# Can you pass a chown command during an rsync call?

Tags: rsync, owner

Title says it all really.

I see that you can preserve owner:group but is it possible to change the owner:group on all files on the remote after they've been synced?

Or can you somehow pipe an extra command?

`rsync -vzrP --delete ~/Sites/website-name/ root@server.com:/home/website-name/public_html/ | chown website-name:websites-group *`

Sorry, my rsync/bash knowledge is pretty limited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `rsync` provides the `--usermap` and `--groupmap` options to allow you to customise how these are mapped at the remote end.

For your particular use case, where *all* files are to be mapped to the same user/group combo, you can use the `--chown` option, which is a shortcut for the above.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply but after searching (and reading the man pages) I can't find anything on ````--usermap --groupmap --chown```` (I found ````--chmod```` only) sorry. Can you point me in the right direction or show me an example of the syntax? Cheers

Comment: Which version of rsync are you using? Those options were added in rsync 3.1.0, and they are described in the [man page](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).

Comment: Thanks for that, I've updated rsync on my mac but the server says 3.0.9 is the latest. I used ````apt-get```` - is there a way to force the server to see the newer versions?

Comment: Well, if your distribution doesn't have 3.1.0 or 3.1.1 packages, you'll have to backport them yourself. See https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingFormalBackports for instructions. I frequently build backport packages myself and I can create one for you, but that might be considered too untrustworthy for you. :-)

Comment: It seems like both client **and server** should be running 3.1.0+ in order to use `--chown`.

Comment: @Jacket Yep, it's a protocol 31 feature.

Comment: so, how do you chown file in rsync with 3.0.9 without backporting rsync to 3.0.10 or 3.1.x ? a pipe could work like in the question ?

Comment: It seems `--chown` doesn't work unless you also set `--owner --group`. It's kind of counter intuitive, since the latter options talk about perserving owner and group from source. On top of that, the man page for `--chown` does not mention that, neither is a warning issued. The section for `--usermap` does mention this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chris's answer, you can also edit your `/etc/rsyncd.conf` and include the `uid` and `gid` you want the files to get in the relevant rsync folder.

Example:

```
[hadoop_out]
        comment =  hadoop_out
        path = /mass1/mt_data/hadoop_out
        read only = no
        list = yes
        uid = 26
        gid = 26
        auth users = postgres
        secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
        hosts allow = 10.11.20.61
```

That way, the files will be sync'ed and saved with `uid` and `gid` `26` of user `postgres` so you will not have to provide this info in the command you run.